# iOS equivalent for Android's include control

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am designing an cross-platform app for iOS aswell Android with a shared logic using MVVMCross (5.1.1).
Throughout my app I have a fixed toolbar at the top displaying the current view's title aswell a button. Below the bar the interface is changing from view to view

### **The Android part:**

On Android I created a reuseable layout which I embed in my current layout using include.

In my portable project I have a BaseViewModel which has the properties the reuseable toolbar layout binds to. Every other ViewModel derives from this base class. This way I can have all bindable properties of a displayed screen in one ViewModel without the need of nesting but see for yourself:

**activity_login.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_login" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLoginLayout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:MvxBind="Text Pin"
                 />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**toolbar_login.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        app:MvxBind="Click ToolbarMenuCommand"
        />
    <!-- some other  -->
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**ViewModels.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Mobile.Helpers;
using ViewModels.Base;
using MvvmCross.Core.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using Plugin.MessageBox;

namespace Mobile.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        protected void NavigateToMainView()
        {
            NavigateTo<MainViewModel>();
        }

        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        protected BaseViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public IMvxCommand ToolbarMenuCommand => new MvxCommand(OnMenuButtonClick);
        protected abstract void OnMenuButtonClick();
    }

    public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _menuVisibility;
        private string _pin;

        public LoginViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
        }

        public bool MenuVisibility
        {
            get => _menuVisibility;
            set => SetProperty(ref _menuVisibility, value);
        }

        public string Pin
        {
            get => _pin;
            set => SetProperty(ref _pin, value);
        }

        protected override void OnMenuButtonClick()
        {
            MenuVisibility = !MenuVisibility;
        }
    }
}
```

### **The iOS part:**

I am not entirely sure how to realise above behavior on iOS. I hope someone has a good idea or a good example project for me which I can take a look at. In general it is no problem to refactorise the ViewModels incase my idea is just not possible at iOS.

A few facts about the iOS project:

- I am **not** using storyboards but single .xib's being independent
  from each other
- In my .xib's files I use autolayout constraints for positioning and
  sizing entirely

A few ideas I already had (cant test them right now):

**1. idea:**

- Create a base .xib with the above bar, the constraints aswell the
  outlets
- Create each new xib Design based on the previously created file

This would mean I need to adjust every view incase I decide to change something about the toolbar but so far I found no other way to embed a .xib in another .xib without having two different ViewControllers. Also I read that inheritance cause problems with outlets.

**2. idea**

- Each .xib has an empty view at the top which acts as a container for
  the toolbar
- Have a Base ViewController which constructs the toolbar from code and
  adds it as a child to the container view, and binds the properties
  from the BaseViewModel

In a previous iOS project I noticed that adding views to the layout can cause problems with autolayout. Probably also a not that good solution?

**3. idea**

Create a xib with the toolbar and a container below and use it as a master page which would probably mean having a MasterViewModel with the toolbar properties and a nested ChildViewModel.
This is probably the way to go but I have to admit that I have no clue what is the best way to approach it (stil pretty new to iOS and MVVMCross).

Does someone have a few useful hints for me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood I think you should try to use ScrollView for iOS part and try to imitate the ViewPager's behavior from Android, an example.